# Обработка ошибок в проекте MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, обработка-ошибок, try-catch

Есть **MVC**-проект, в нём несколько десятков контроллеров с кучей различных методов.

Неужели тело каждого метода нужно оборачивать в **try/catch**, чтобы отлавливать исключения? 
   Есть ли инструменты, которые помогут это сделать грамотно?

Comment: Пробовали пользоваться фильтрами для ловли исключений? Или смотрели на глобальные обработчики исключений?

Comment: Не нашел примера использования глобального обработчика(( надо еще поискать...а фильтры-то зачем?)

Comment: Вы можете создать фильтр для обработки ошибок как для контроллера, так и для действия. Вы можете использовать глобальные обработчики ошибок (в зависимости от фреймворка, что вы используете, вы же его не указали). Если не знаете, что гуглить, вот [раз](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/8.3.php), [два](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine), [три](https://www.milevis.com/tips/details/global-error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc), [четыре](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Прошу прощения. Действительно не указал фреймворк. Использую NLOG. Спасибо за ссылки!!!

Comment: про фреймворк я имел ввиду `asp.net mvc` или `asp.net mvc core`

Comment: он был указан в тегах...

Comment: я видел, просто их часто путают, ведь по сути asp.net core  - тоже asp.net mvc :) Ну, сейчас для нас это уже все равно не важно.

Comment: Мне по этому поводу очень нравиться предложение Дино Эспозито: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/pragmatic-web-error-handling-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, обработку исключений вынести в отедльную middleware, тогда код action'a может вполне себе бросать exception а в middleware ты его можешь обработать и сообщить юзеру не 500 ise, а что то более человеческое)). [Тут](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brandonh/2017/07/31/using-middleware-to-trap-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/) и [Тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.0) можно узнать подробности.

Получиться что то вроде этого 
(startup)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```